# CLR Assembly for Encryption/Decryption

Tags: c#, sql-server, encryption, assemblies, clr

We recently implemented some symmetric keys in MS SQL 2005 for encrypting and decrypting credit card, check routing/account numbers.

Ideally, we would like a user defined function to be able to perform the encryption and decryption, however, its not possible since the encryptbykey and decryptbykey functions cannot be used within user defined functions.

Initially I thought we could create a CLR Assembly (in C#) with functions to do this, however, as I learned the same rules apply.

I was wondering what others have been doing to easily perform this functionality. Creating many stored procedures such as:

OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY...
SELECT username, decryptByKey(...) AS password
CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY...

... for the many areas in which we will encrypt/decrypt would be very tedious.

Comment: You're decrypting passwords?  Really?  You know that's not good design at all.  Passwords should be one-way hashed.  Decryptable keys renders every single password in your database vulnerable.

Comment: Well mainly I will be using it for credit card numbers, and check routing/ account numbers.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest doing some research in encryption/security if you're working with this kind of sensitive information.  Better to be well prepared than sorry!

Comment: I'm migrating our current system from an ordering system whose encryption was horribly easy to decipher... so this is definitely a step in the right direction. :)

Comment: I use rot13 twice for extra protection! :D

Comment: @Will Some databases do store passwords to other's systems, case in point gmail's pop3 fetching service.

I'd say do the decryption as late as possible and encryption as early as possible. Database is not safe place to have data decrypted at some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether it's a good idea or not, what about a stored procedure with output parameter to achieve the same as a udf?

Comment: That exactly what I've ended up doing. I'm creating a C# assembly sp ... created as an assembly to hide the certificate passwords